# Is there anyway to detect the margin of a div?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to know the margin-left of div1, so I can use it in my code.  Setting it this way, the margin on the left will change depending on the screen size. How can I detect the margin left of this div?

```
<div class="max-w-6xl m-auto">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In react, you can make use of the `ref` callback, which receives the HTML DOM element as an argument. Inside of this callback, you could query the `margin-left` style from the element and store it in a state. Here's an example:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [marginLeft, setMarginLeft] = useState(0); // in pixels

  const retrieveMargin = (elm) => {
    if (elm != null) {
      let styles = window.getComputedStyle(elm);
      let ml = styles.getPropertyValue("margin-left");
      setMarginLeft(Number.parseInt(ml.replace("px", "")));
    }
  };

  return <div class="mydiv" ref={retrieveMargin}></div>;
};
```

Comment: this works, what if the user is constantly changing the screen size. Is there a way to update marginLeft, without having to refresh?

Comment: In that case you would have to setup a hook with `useRef` and have `retrieveMargin` use that specific ref. Then inside of a `useEffect` callback that only runs once, you can set `retrieveMargin` as the callback for the `resize` event on the window.

Comment: Do you have an example you can show?